# How to properly store valuable guitars?

Tags: guitar, maintenance, storage

What are the general guidelines when storing a collectors, very nice guitar (special woods, etc.), or one you value greatly? You will find humidity control systems in place at stores with "acoustic guitar rooms" for example.  Is is good to store a guitar in a case for very long?  Should some sort of moisture control be added to any case that is intended to sit for very long or be in a less than ideal environment?